# Prove $p\land q \implies r \vdash p\implies ( q \implies r)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I have this proof

[image]

I'm confused because from what I understand the $\vdash$ means that whenever the left-hand side is true, then the right hand side also is.

If I assume p and q are true and work my logic from there, doesn't that exclude other possibilities? For example what if p and r are true but q is false? Maybe I'm reading this wrong. Is the left hand side equivalent to $p\land (q \implies r)$?

My second question is, I have a different way of solving this but I don't know how to write it like a proof. Basically if the left hand side is true then $p$ and $q \implies r$ have to be both true. By modus ponens, this makes the right hand side true (if p is true then $p \implies (q \implies r)$ is equivalent to $q \implies r$ , and since p is also true then $1\implies 1$ is true, q.e.d). How do I write this like in the example?

Comment: $p \land q \implies r$ here means $(p \land q) \implies r$ and that is not equivalent to $p \land (q \implies r)$. (Why you have to read $p \land q \implies r$ as $(p \land q) \implies r$ depends on the conventions that you are adopting: it's either because you are evaluating connectives from left to right or because $\land$ has higher precedence than $\implies$. I have never come across any source that evaluates connectives from right to left and gives $\land$ and $\implies$ equal precedence.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm confused because from what I understand the ⊢ means that whenever the left-hand side is true, then the right hand side also is.

That is the definition for semantic entailment, or models, $\models$.

Syntactic entailment, or derives, $\vdash$, means that the the right-hand-side can be *infered* from the left-hand-side, using the syntactic proof system you are using (the diagram indicates that is a natural deduction system).

> If I assume p and q are true and work my logic from there, doesn't that exclude other possibilities? For example what if p and r are true but q is false?

The other possibilities are *irrelevant* to the prof.   You just want to show a derivation of $p\to(q\to r)$ from $(p\land q)\to r$ -- that the premise implies that an assumption of $p$ then of $q$ will let you infer $r$.   To do that, you need *not care* what happens when you assume *other things*, such as $p$ and $\lnot q$.

(The map says if I turn left here and there I will get to where I want to go.  Well the map does not say what happens if I turn right at either place, but really, I just want to know if *following the map* will get me where I want to go.)

Answer (score 1):

Answering your first question about the right hand side, assuming $p$ is true, we are left to prove $q \implies r$. If $q$ was false, you can't conclude anything about $r$. It can be either true or false! That's why we assume $p$ is true in the first place: if the whole relation is indeed true, assuming $p$ is true should lead us to conclude that $q \implies r$ is true. Since this is also a conditional, we again assume the antecedent ($q$) is true and try to conclude the consequent ($r$). As for the left hand side, the $\land$ operator has higher precedence, so it reads as $(p \land q) \implies r$. That's why we can reach step 5 from 1 and 4 (using *modus ponens*).

By now, you should be able know the answer for your second question. What you have is not $p \land (q \implies r)$, but $(p \land q) \implies r$.